# Using Python to plot in Excel 2010 vs Excel 2003

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7

I have a Python (2.7.5) application that processes and plots data from text files in Excel 2003. It works very dandily, but now that they're upgrading us all to Office 2010 the plot part doesn't work anymore. It is creating a plot, but it is configured totally incorrectly.

Is there any easy way to modify my code for plotting in Excel 2003 to plot in Excel 2010? Here is what works well in Excel 2003:

```
chart = xlApp.Charts.Add()
    series = chart.SeriesCollection(1)
    series.XValues = xlSheet.Range("L13:L200")
    series.Values = xlSheet.Range("M13:M200")
    chart.Legend.Delete() # Delete legend; MUST BE DONE BEFORE CHART IS MOVED
    series.Name = file
    chart.Location(2, xlSheet.Name) # Copy chart to active worksheet
    chart = xlSheet.Shapes(1)
    chart.Top = 51
    chart.Left = 240
    chart.Width = 500
    chart.Height = 350
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is a big phrase. What about the code doesn't work? What about the configuration is wrong?

Comment: It's plotting a data range that seems to be totally unrelated to the range I specify in the code. It's also plotting a column plot, whereas I want a scatter plot.